# Finding $A$ and $B$ using $ A \times B = \text{lcm}\,(A,B)\times\text{hcf}\,(A,B)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The highest common factor and lowest common multiple of two numbers $A$ and $B$ are $12$ and $168$ respectively. Find the possible values of $A$ and $B$ with the exception of $12$ and $168$.

I know this question involves the concept of 
$ A \times B =  \text{lcm}\,(A,B)\times\text{hcf}\,(A,B)$

But I'm not sure how to apply it. Can someone guide me? Thanks!

Comment: The HCF of $16$ is not divisible by the GCF of $12$, so there are no possible values for $A$ and $B$. Are you sure you didn't mean that the HCF was $168$?

Comment: Since $\operatorname{hcf}(A,B)=12$, we can write, $A=12a$ and $B=12b$ with $\operatorname{hcf}(a,b)=1$. Then $\operatorname{lcm}(A,B)=12ab$. Now we are given that $12ab=168$. This implies $ab=14$ with $\operatorname{hcf}(a,b)=1$. The only possible solutions for $ab$ (assuming they are positive integers) are $a=2,b=7$ or $a=1, b=14$ or $a=7,b=2$ or $a=14, b=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Using your formula, you know that $AB=12\times168=2016$. If you factorize $2016$ then you get some possible values of $A$ and $B$.

For example, $2\times 1008=2016$, so we might try $A=2$ and $B=1008$. But then we don't have $\text{hcf}\,(A,B)=12$, so this doesn't work.

So one approach would be to find all the factor pairs of $2016$, find which ones satisfy the given conditions, and then make sure (by a logical argument) that no other possibilities exist.

---

Of course, I'm assuming $A$ and $B$ are meant to be positive integers. If you include negative integers, then there are really a lot of possibilities.